# Google Visualization API - set color to specific point

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Does anybody know how to set specific color to a point on a chart?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official documentation for changing color of each bar, However there is an simple trick to achieve this. You can use `isStacked:true` and overlap two bars. Use second bar if you need only other color.

[image: Final Output]

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        // Add columns
        data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
        data.addColumn('number', 'value');
        data.addColumn('number','value');//Used for red bar

        data.addRows(5);
        data.setCell(0, 0, 'Category 1');
        data.setCell(0, 1, 4.25);
        data.setCell(1, 0, 'Category 2');
        data.setCell(1, 1, 2.5);
        data.setCell(2, 0, 'Category 3');
        data.setCell(2, 1, 3.5);
        data.setCell(3, 0, 'Category 4');

        data.setCell(3, 2, 4.5);//Used because we need red or other color bar
        data.setCell(4, 0, 'Category 5');
        data.setCell(4, 1, 3.75);



        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data,{isStacked: true});
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can check a quick demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sXmzq/
​

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare all the colors to use for your column chart.  There's no reason they can't be duplicated with one different like `['blue','blue','blue','red','blue']` or what have you.

It's explained under "colors" [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't help. I use one series in the chart and I need to emphasize one point in it. `colors` option is used to specify colors per series, not per point.